# DisplayGroup decorator in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I'm using DisplayGroup to render a couple of elements in a group. Now what I want to do, is render this group in a single table row. But it turns out, that Decorators on DisplayGroups do **NOT** work the same way they do on simple elements. An example:

```
 $content = $this->getDisplayGroup('group');
 $content->setDecorators(array(
      'FormElements',
       array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'table', 'class' => 'element')),
        ));
```

This just puts
`<table></table>` at the end of my DisplayGroup. I've also tried to alias them:

```
array(array('elementDiv' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'table')),
'FormElements',
array(array('td' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'table')),
```

Still puts them in one place, not both tried `openOnly` and `closeOnly` :

```
array(array('elementDiv' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'table','openOnly'=>true)),
'FormElements',
array(array('td' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'table','closeOnly'=>true)),
```

And it still puts in only the closing tag. If I change these to `<td>`, everything works fine, but not with `<table>` Am I missing something?

Comment: The `HtmlTag` decorator does not discriminate on tag so it should be working fine. When you say it puts the table tags at the end of your display group, is that in the actual rendered source?

Comment: Yes. It just puts the open and close tags side by side in the position, where I place the decorator in the stack.

Comment: I've just tried this and seemed to get the same result, but I am using firebug to inspect the rendered markup and I found that, actually, the table tags are enclosing the display group (and I can see this if I view page source and also if I step through the code in Zend/Form/Decorator/HtmlTag.php). So in my case, it's firebug's interpretation of the rendered markup which is not as I expected - perhaps you have a similar issue.

Comment: I was always looking at it through view-generated source on my Developers Toolbar in Mozilla. It could be though, that these things are somehow tied together. Will have to give it another go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, *jah* was right, and the table not being added was really a bug of source viewers.

```
$group->setDecorators(array(

            'FormElements',
        array('Description', array('escape' => false, 'tag' => false)),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'table', 'class' => 'element')),
));
```

This did the trick for me. Not really sure what the Description Decorator does, but the table renders as needed.