# PHP stripping "/" in closing tag of img

Tags: php, xhtml, string-concatenation

**I have this inside a while loop:**

```
echo '<a class="thumbnail" href="./images/bus-photos/'.$row['file'].'">';
echo '<img alt="'.$row['caption'].'"'. 'src="./images/bus-photos/thumbs/tmb'.$row['file'].'"/></a>';
```

**It outputs this:**

```
<img src="./images/bus-photos/thumbs/tmb134-trap-door.jpg" alt="Trap Door">
```

I just cant seem to get the image tag closed...sad but true.

Comment: how can it output the src before the caption? by output you mean HTML source output or firebug output?

Comment: did you view source or did you check it in firebug/some-other-debugger? firebug normalizes your view, and is not a way of viewing the **actual** source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you're using Firebug or some other kind of DOM inspector to view the source. Don't do this if you *actually* want to see what your HTML looks like. Use "View Source" or your browser's equivalent.

Don't use "View Generated Source" (Web Developer Add-On) either as that still builds the source document from the DOM. See [DisplayGroup decorator in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315967/displaygroup-decorator-in-zend-framework)

---

Another thing that will probably help... It's usually easier to follow mixed markup and server-side printing if you break in and out of the server-side context. For example

```
<img
    alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['caption']) ?>"
    src="./images/bus-photos/thumbs/tmb<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['file']) ?>"
    />
```

Comment: Yep, Firebug. View Source shows: <img alt="Trap Door"/src="./images/bus-photos/thumbs/tmb134-trap-door.jpg"/> So there is a trailing "/" after the alt value.

Comment: @Jamie Other than your redundant close/open string and lack of space between `alt` and `src`, I can't see any errors or where the slash is coming from. I've edited my answer to provide some hints on mixing PHP and HTML

Comment: I added a space between alt and src, and it fixed it. Since this inside a loop, it doesn't look like I can go out of PHP, but the extra effort is much appreciated. I will have a look at the htmlspecialchars() function. Just getting into the server side stuff. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: You can close and reopen the PHP context anywhere. The logic of the PHP control statements will be preserved and will "embed" the non-PHP part. I.e. and `if(false){ ?> [html here] <?php }` will not output this HTML withing the curly brackets.

Comment: @Jamie Check out the [PHP alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), it's perfect for these sorts of templating tasks

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you're using some HTML-cleanup-library in PHP that strips out the slash - in HTML, you don't need to close some elements, for example images and newlines. Leave it out.

Comment: Good point. The doctype is xhtml, so I need to close the image tags. I have changed the tag of the post from HTML to XHTML. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is wrong.  That output clearly did not come from the code you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add no value.

Comment: @Jamie - echo **does not** manipulate the data it's given to print.  Therefore, the code you've posted **cannot** have caused that output.  Post more of your code so we can see what's going on

Comment: That entirely depends on how that output is interpreted before presentation ;)